# reading multiple lines in a txt file not working in php

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to read a txt file with multiple lines and console.log it but I'm running into an error. The error only persists when trying to read a file with multiple lines. If the txt file only has one line it works perfectly and console.logs the line. I have tried using the fgets method and file_get_contents method but they both produce the same error which is `SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`. What is wrong with my code. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```html
<?php
  $file = fopen("test.txt","r");
  $let = fgets($file); //Don't work
  $let = file_get_contents("test.txt"); //Don't work
  fclose($file);
?>

<script>
  var val = "<?=$let?>";
  console.log(val); //error: SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
</script>
```

Comment: plz share sample txt file you are trying

Comment: why does that matter?

Comment: we can see what content it has and if it is breaking because of some special chars, etc

Comment: it's a normal txt file with no special chars but the answer below solved the problem. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: Got it. It is double quote which is creating issue in `var val = "<?=$let?>"`. Instead use this `var val = \`<?=$let?>\``.

Comment: yeah that was the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The string returned by `fgets()` will end with a newline, but JavaScript string literals can't contain newline. Also, if the string contains a double quote, that will cause a syntax error because you're using that as the JavaScript string delimiter.

Use `json_encode()` to encode the string as a JavaScript literal properly.

```
var val = <?=json_encode($let);?>;
```

Comment: this dealt with the error but fgets is only reading the first line only. Shouldn't it read the whole file if no length Is assigned?

Comment: Of course not. The definition of `fgets()` is to read the next line.

Comment: You're confusing `fgets()` with `fread()`.